# phpspreadsheet: How to add some margin between a cell and the image?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

When inserting an image into a cell, it gets inserted to the very left of the cell, I'd like to add some margin, how to do so?

I tried many things, I'm not the first to ask this, it's being asked since the days of PHPexcel and there's no answer, I tried every solution to no avail, like this one, which should center whatever is in the cell, it centers text but not images

```
function center(){
$styleArray = [
    'alignment' => [
        'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
        'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
    ],
];
return $styleArray;
}
$sheet->getStyle('B2')->applyFromArray(center()));
```

I'm not necessarily trying to center it, whatever works, all I need is some margin between the cell and the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setOffsetX` like this

```
$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
$drawing->setPath('../assets/img/logo.png');
$drawing->setWidthAndHeight(158, 72);
$drawing->setResizeProportional(true);

$drawing->setOffsetX(10);    // this is how
$drawing->setOffsetY(3);    // this is how
```

Comment: I'm inserting the image in a merged cell. When i do the merge everything becomes one column

Comment: Ok. Other simple soulution is to make around the image a white border. There is also the drawing option setOffsetX maybe this is what you looking for.

Comment: I edited your answer in order to clarify how to use `setOffsetX`, such that it becomes a valid answer I can accept.